# Передача значения UF_

Tags: битрикс

Приветствую.
Имеется стандартный компонент каталог.
У части разделов первого уровня задано пользовательское свойство UF_SHOW (тип да/нет)
Определяю это значение в резалт_модифире шаблона 
Собственно не могу понять как мне в файле section_horizontal.php узнать это значение?
Что хочу сделать: если свойство раздела в статусе ДА - то категории второго уровня выводить в одном дизайне, если нет - то в другом.

Answer (score 0):

В `section_horizontal.php` как раз идет подключение компонента `catalog.section`, а в этот компонент передается параметр id раздела, поэтому в `section_horizontal.php` посмотри массив `$arResult`, в этом массиве должно быть значение `$arResult['VARIABLES']['SECTION_ID']`, и затем в данном файле через класс CIBlockSection запрашивай нужное свойство с фильтром.